# Is there a way to show the matching element of a specific case using the grepl function in R?

Tags: r, grepl

I checked whether the brands of the data frame "df1"

```
 brands
1 Nike   
2 Adidas  
3 D&G
```

are to be found in the elements of the following column of the data frame "df2"

```
statements 
1 I love Nike   
2 I don't like Adidas   
3 I hate Puma
```

For this I use the code:

```
subset_df2 <- df2[grepl(paste(df1$brands, collapse="|"), ignore.case=TRUE, df2$statements), ]
```

The code works and I get a subset of df2 containing only the lines with the desired brands:

```
 statements*
1 I love Nike   
2 I don't like Adidas
```

Is there also a way to display which element of the cells from df2$statements exactly matches with df1$brands? For instance, a vector like [Nike, Adidas]. So, I only want to get the Nike and Adidas elements as my output and not the whole statement.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
brands <- c("nike", "adidas", "d&g")  # lower-case here
text <- c("I love Nike", "I love Adidas")
ptns <- paste(brands, collapse = "|")
ptns
# [1] "nike|adidas|d&g"
text2 <- text[NA]
text2[grepl(ptns, text, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- gsub(paste0(".*(", ptns, ").*"), "\\1", text, ignore.case = TRUE)
text2
# [1] "Nike"   "Adidas"
```

The pre-assignment of `text[NA]` is because `gsub` will make no change if the pattern is not found. I'm using `text[NA]`, but we could also use `rep(NA_character_, length(text))`, it's the same effect.

If you need multiple matches per `text`, then perhaps

```r
brands <- c("Nike", "Adidas", "d&g")
text <- c("I love nike", "I love Adidas and Nike")
ptns <- paste(brands, collapse = "|") 
gre <- gregexpr(ptns, text, ignore.case = TRUE)
sapply(regmatches(text, gre), paste, collapse = ";")
# [1] "nike"        "Adidas;Nike"
```

Comment: Please demonstrate in your sample data what that looks like, both with matching data and the output from multiple matches.

Comment: this works fine, but only one match per cell is displayed at a time, even if multiple brands are mentioned in a statement. Is there a way to display all matches that exist within one statement?

Comment: Sure, something like this: 

brands <- c("Nike", "Adidas", "d&g")  
text <- c("I love nike", "I love Adidas and Nike")
ptns <- paste(brands, collapse = "|")
text2 <- text[NA]
text2[grepl(ptns, text, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- gsub(paste0(".*(", ptns, ").*"), "\\1", text, ignore.case = TRUE)
> text2
[1] "nike" "Nike"

In this case, the “optimal” ouput would be "nike" "Nike; Adidas", since both brands are mentioned in the second statement.

Comment: See my edit, MaxSchmidt